# HTML AGILITY PACK: Using Proxies?

Tags: html-agility-pack

How do I use proxies with HAP? This is what I have so far...(with no luck).

IPCHICKEN is just used to test the ip address. it is showing my ip address and not the ip address of my proxy

```
Function GetPrice(ByVal AmazonURL As String, ByVal Delay As Integer)
    Dim aHtml As New HtmlWeb
        Dim ChromeAgent As String = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11"
    aHtml.UserAgent = ChromeAgent


    Dim proxy As New System.Net.WebProxy
    Dim proxyAddress As New Uri("http://111.111.111/")


    Dim aDoc As HtmlDocument = aHtml.Load("http://www.ipchicken.com", "GET", proxy, System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials)

    Dim aNode As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
    aNode = aDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='olpDivId']/span[2]")

    If aNode.InnerText Is Nothing Then

    End If

    Dim UsedPrice1 As String = aNode.InnerText
    Dim i As Integer = UsedPrice1.IndexOf("$")
    Dim UsedPrice As Integer = UsedPrice1.Substring(i + 1)

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Delay)

    Return UsedPrice
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like the following. Depending on the page you mightn't need the UTF8 conversion.

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("proxyname", 8080);
proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Proxy = proxy;

string baseHtml = "";

byte[] pageContent = client.DownloadData("your target url");

UTF8Encoding utf = new UTF8Encoding();
baseHtml = utf.GetString(pageContent);

HtmlDocument pageHtml = new HtmlDocument();
pageHtml.LoadHtml(baseHtml);
```